# Using CORS in Nginx, how can I overwrite Access-Control-Allow-Origin on a location?

Tags: php, nginx, cors

In my `api.hostname.com` host file I have:

```
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "https://hostname.com";
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true";

location /different/path/ {
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
}
```

With the intention that `https://api.hostname.com` is only accessible to `https://hostname.com` while files in `/different/path/` are accessible anywhere (public API).

Internally all seems well, but the override simply isn't working with the error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.hostname.com/different/path/data.php' from origin 'https://other.co.uk' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://hostname.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

How can I override the default setting for a location?

---

Headers (truncated) for within the `hostname.com` domain are:

```
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://hostname.com
```

Headers when called from a third-party are the same on preflight but I don't see any CORS related headers for the actual fetch request.

---

If I remove the `server` block CORS headers I get this error when thrying to access from a third party:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

If I then add headers to the PHP script everything works fine:

```
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

As a workaround I have added the relevant headers to the PHP scripts in my APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I use below nginx config:

```
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "https://hostname.com";
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true";

location /different/path/ {
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
    return 200 $uri;
}
```

The add_header works well for location `/different/path`, when I access it, the response header is 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'. Which in your case is not, check if you have other configration, or have you reload the config.

```
curl -Ss -I server.test/different/path/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 19 Jan 2024 01:10:44 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=25
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *


$ curl -Ss -I server.test/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 19 Jan 2024 01:10:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=25
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://hostname.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Comment: I've reloaded the config, I even stop/started Nginx just to be sure.

Where else might there be conflicting config, I searched my repo and there aren't any headers being set in the PHP. Not sure where else I should look?

I've added relevant header info to the original post.